# Selecionar elementos HTML inserido dinâmicamente com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou desenvolvendo uma espécie de calculadora, onde o cliente coloca algumas informações listadas em elementos "select" e calcula o valor do serviço a ser contratado. Nessa calculadora, há a opção de selecionar o tipo de serviço ao qual o cliente quer calcular os preços, isso é, os parâmetros "name" e "id" mudam de acordo com a seleção do serviço do parte do cliente. Segue abaixo os códigos

HTML

```
<section class="wrapper style1 align-center">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h2>Calcule Preços de Planos</h2>
                        <p id="ccl">Simule valores para contratar avulso ou planos periódicos. </p>
                        <h3>Calculando para:</h3>
                        <div class="items style1 medium sem-borda no-padding-top">
                            <div class="field third">
                                <input type="radio" id="ph" name="setserv" value="ph" onClick="setCalc()" checked />
                                <label for="ph">Diarista Por Hora</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field third">
                                <input type="radio" id="po" name="setserv" value="po" onClick="setCalc()" />
                                <label for="po">Limpeza Pós Obra</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="items style1 medium onscroll-fade-in calculadora">
                                <section id="calc-tit-desc">

                                </section>
                                <section id="calc-parametros">

                                </section>
                                <section class="calc-preco">
                                    <div class="preco">
                                        <h2 id="calc-preco" class=""></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="actions">
                                        <li>
                                            <span class="button special">Quero Contratar!</span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </section>
                        </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function setCalcPO() {

    ctd.innerHTML = calcTitDescPO;
    cpa.innerHTML = calcParametrosPO;
    calcPreco.innerHTML = "R$0,00";

}

function setCalcPH() {

    ctd.innerHTML = calcTitDescPH;
    cpa.innerHTML = calcParametrosPH;
    calcPreco.innerHTML = "R$0,00";

}

function setCalc() {


        if (isEasy()) {
            setCalcEasy();
        } else if (isPO()) {
            setCalcPO();
        } else if (isPH()) {
            setCalcPH();
        }   

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    setCalc();

});
```

As funções acima inserem um bloco HTML nas section #calc-tit-desc e #calc-paramentros que são os textos que descrevem o serviço que está sendo calculado e os parâmetros (elementos select) a serem escolhidos pelo cliente. O problema surge do fato de que após a inserção do conteúdo HTML pelo javascript, os valores do select não podem ser acessados, dado que o erro aparece como "não é possível encontrar um valor de um nulo", ou seja, o javascript não consegue encontrar aquele select inserido depois de carregado a página.

Código que é inserido pelo dinâmicamente

```
var calcTitDescPO = '<h3 id="calc-tit">Calculando Para Pós Obra</h3>'+
            '<p id="calc-desc">Calcule o valor do serviço de acordo com o tamanho do ambiente e do nível de contaminação por cimento, tinta, argamassa etc.</p>';

var calcParametrosPO = '<div class="select-wrapper">'+
                    '<select name="tamanho-obra" id="tamanho-obra" >'+
                        '<option value="1">- TAMANHO M² -</option>'+
                        '<option value="50">Até 50 m²</option>'+
                        '<option value="100">De 50 à 100 m²</option>'+
                        '<option value="150">De 100 à 150 m²</option>'+
                        '<option value="200">De 150 à 200 m²</option>'+
                        '<option value="maior200">Acima de 200</option>'+
                    '</select><br />'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="select-wrapper">'+
                    '<select name="contaminacao" id="contaminacao">'+
                        '<option value="1">- CONTAMINAÇÃO -</option>'+
                        '<option value="sem">Sem contaminação</option>'+
                        '<option value="baixo">Baixo</option>'+
                        '<option value="medio">Médio</option>'+
                        '<option value="alto">Alto</option>'+
                        '<option value="critico">Crítico</option>'+
                    '</select>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<ul class="actions margintop">'+
                    '<li>'+
                        '<span class="button" id="calc-botao" onclick="calcularObra()">Calcular</span>'+
                    '</li>'+
                '</ul>';
```

Selecionando os valores dos seletores

```
var obraTamanho = document.getElementById("tamanho-obra");
var contaminacao = document.getElementById("contaminacao");
```

function calcularObra() {

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if(obraTamanho.value !== 0 && contaminacao.value === 0) {
        cpe.innerHTML = "Falta informar o nível de contaminação";
    } else if (obraTamanho.value === 0 && contaminacao.value !== 0) {
        cpe.innerHTML = "Falta informar o tamanho do local";
    }


});
```

}

E ai usando else if sucessivamente para os dados escolhidos

Alguém sabe como posso contornar isso?

Grato desde já

Comment: Fabio, está faltando código aí não está?

Comment: Só estão faltando as variáveis que guardam o código HTML que é inserido nas section mencionadas. Coloquei-as concatenando linha por linha, vou inserir o código na pergunta, desculpe

Comment: @FábioEspíndola Ainda falta mostrar o código que usa para selecionar os elementos, não?

Comment: Adicionado também

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você não postou todo o código, mas eu já passei por um problema parecido, ao criar um botão dinamicamente o evento "click" não funcionava nos botões criados.

Eu tentava pegar o evento da seguinte forma:

```
$("#idBotao").click(function() {

});
```

Assim alterei a forma de pegar o evento e funcionou:

```
$("#idBotao").on( "click", function() {

});
```